# Bitcoin Core 0.19.1 RPC "Move" command

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I want to move some coins from a wallet to an other, so I found `move` command which is supported in `Bitcoin Core 0.17.0 RPC` but not in `0.19.1`. Is any other command has been added instead of `move`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous account system has been deprecated and removed. Current versions of Bitcoin expect you to either manage address<=>account links in your own software, or use different wallets for things you previously used accounts for.

If you are managing it in your own software, it is a simple matter of making an off chain transfer from one account to another in your own database.

If you are using multiple wallets, you will have to make an on chain transaction to send Bitcoin to an address in the destination wallet.

Comment: This question came to my mind when I tried to send some coins (via `sendtoaddress`) from `wallet A` to `wallet B` Which both are on my node but the balance of `wallet A` was deducted and not added to the balance of `wallet B`. does transferring coins between wallets that are on the same node need sending on chain transaction? does this transaction includes fee?

Comment: There should be an on-chain transaction that wallet B is able to pick up, especially if they are on the same node - it will incur a transaction fee.